# Why am I continuously getting this answer wrong for method of undetermined coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on solving this inhomogeneous problem with the method of undetermined coefficients using tips from this website: [Paul's online math notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx). There is an equation halfway down that looks almost exactly the same as mine, so I referenced it for help, but I'm still not getting the right answer. The equation is this:
$$y''-2y'+y=te^t$$
I started out with my "guess" equation as: $Y_P(t)=e^t(At+B)$

Then I took the first and second derivatives:
$$Y_P'(t)=e^tAt+Be^t+Ae^t$$
$$Y_P''(t)=e^tAt+2Ae^t+Be^t$$

After finding that I plugged in the three equations to the LHS of the original equation and then separated like terms:

$$e^tt(A-2A+A)+e^t(2A+B-2A-2B+B)=te^t$$
In each of the parentheses I end up with a value of $0$, which can't be right. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $1$ is a *double* root of the characteristic equation, so that the left side operator annihilates both $e^t$ and $te^t$ (which falls out of your calculation).

Try a cubic polynomial multiplied by $e^t$ to find your particular solution. (It's cubic because the polynomial you started with has degree $1$ and you have a double root, so then $1+2=3$.) You can save yourself some time by writing it as $t^2(At+B)e^t$, because any lower power terms will just get annihilated anyway, so they don't meaningfully contribute to the particular solution.

Comment: I tried this and it was absolutely horrendous, but I got $A={1\over 6}$ and $B=0$. I don't expect anyone to do this for themselves, but do these answers seem reasonable?